# Can show the recently viewed content based on the User?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have used the statistics module for showing the most recently viewed content in a view. But the content will be added only by the administrator.

In Relationship, I can get only the content:author. so the user who have created the content they can only view the content. If the user are not authored any content, the result will not be shown.

How could I pass the current user in the contextual filter without the content:authored.

Or how could I customise the statistics most recently viewed view based on the user id instead of using flag+rules modules and recently viewed module.?

Comment: I haven't got an answer off the top of my head but I can tell you that you cannot use the drupal core statistics module for this as it doesn't store the data required to identify views per user. There are a number of more comprehensive statistics modules though.

Answer (score 1):

You can user [recently_read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read) Module for show history of the recent viewed nodes. Hope this will help.